# Changing decimal format of a calculated field in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

In one of my DocuSign templates, I have a fixed table and a summary row at the bottom. In the summary row, all above cells in the column are summaries with a formula field. The calculated amount, however, returns the result using a UK/US decimal format:
[link to a picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2hnL.png)

Is it possible to change the result from "1,235,678.00" to "1.235.678,00"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to change the decimal formal of a calculated field through settings as of the time of this writing. I contacted DocuSign support and I was referred to my account manager to have this fixed. I recommend to anyone walking in these shoes to either contact DocuSign support or contacting their account manager directly!